# Split string with comma only not between parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I search regex for split string with comma only not between parenthesis in python:

Exemple:

```
string = '(parent son, daugther  , father ), sister'
```

expected result:

```
['(parent son, daugther  , father )', 'sister']
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, regex are not good at matching nesting / recursive structures. So while it *might* be possible to succeed, you'd have a much easier time doing the splitting by hand e.g.

```py
groups = []
nesting = 0
idx = 0
for group in re.finditer(r'[,\(\)]', string):
    assert nesting >= 0
    if group[0] == '(':
        nesting += 1
    elif group[0] == ')':
        nesting -= 1
    elif nesting > 0:
        continue # ignore commas in parens
    else:
        groups.append(string[idx:group.start()].strip())
        idx = group.end()
# after last group
groups.append(string[idx:].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, I would go with regex split using positive lookbehind i.e splitting the string at comma (and spaces after if any) that is preceded by closing round bracket:

```py
import re

string = '(parent son, daugther  , father ), sister'

output = re.split(r'(?<=\)),\s+', string)
# ['(parent son, daugther  , father )', 'sister']
```

Comment: What about `string = '(parent son, daugther  , father ), sister, uncle'`?

Comment: You should have clarify your question and use a complete example otherwise answering it will be difficult for all

Comment: This is not my question.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) instead of re, you can use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
import regex

str = '(parent son, daugther  , father ), sister'
res = regex.split(r'\(.+?\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,', str)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['(parent son, daugther  , father )', ' sister']
```

#### How it works:

- `\(.+?\)` is trying to match opening and closing parenthesis with some data inside
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` if parens are found, then discard the match
- `|` else
- `,` match a comma. At this point, we are sure it is not between parens.